# Trying to put img in a tag in CSS

Tags: css, hyperlink

I have a really newbie CSS issue. I want to put an `img` in `a` and make `img` element clickable on its whole surface.

Here is my code :

```
<header class="mobile">
    <div class="click-nav">
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="" class="clicker"><img src="..."></a>
            <ul>
               <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        <div>
    </div>

    <div id="logo">
        <a href="#/index"><img src="..."></a>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
```

What drives me mad is that it perfectly works for my `logo` div but not for my `nav` div.

I tried to fix it by setting `a` to :block (or inline-block) with height and width values. I tried to set `img` width to 100%... I even tried to cheat with `inline-height` attribute...  But nothing works !

When looking the inspector, I can underline my `a` tag and I even see his clickable surface growing when size values are set but I still can't click it on chrome or partially in other browsers.

**About my CSS**: 
I reset my CSS and didn't add any rules to a links and parents div don't are just have absolute position.
Any tip is welcome, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't click it" ?

Comment: I mean there isn't pointer cursor and no way to click on it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you have this problem.
I test for the `nav` and `div` tag, but both work well

```
<nav class="logo">
   <a href="#/index"><img src="http://goo.gl/FyWYfQ"></a>
</div>
<div class="logo">
   <a href="#/index"><img src="http://goo.gl/FyWYfQ"></a>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/294LA/)

I think you can give the complete code of your HTML and CSS file.
(I mean the `nav` code and `div` code)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div class="nav">
            <a href="" class="clicker"><img src="..."></a>
</div>
```

and if it didn't work try this:

```
<a href="" class="clicker"><img src="..."></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for all you replies. My problem was I set my header to `display:inline` -for some reasons- so my `a` inherited

Comment: anchors are inline elements anyway - display css doesn't inherit unless you specify for it to do so